# Differences between 'altogether' and 'at all'

Tags: word-usage, difference

Do **'at all'** and **'altogether'** have any difference in their meanings

And if they haven't got any difference, does this sentence:

> *"It wasn't interesting **altogether**."*

Mean:

> *"It wasn't interesting **at all**."*

Comment: It wasn't altogether interesting. OR Altogether, it wasn't interesting. altogether = overall, not at all. See a dictionary....

Comment: If we say that something was not altogether interesting, we generally mean that it was partly interesting (non-zero interest). If something was not at all interesting, it was not interesting in any way (zero interest).